# How to convert touch point to CG vector

Tags: ios, swift, touch, skaction, cgpoint

I'm trying to get the player to move to the direction of the player touch without stopping, or direction of swipe would be better because it seems more natural. However I only can find out how to do so with SKAction.move(by: vector) but the location variable I get from touches.first is a CG point.

I'm not sure what a vector point is so I can't figure out how to convert the touch point to a vector point to make this happen.

Any help would be really appreciated. I'm almost finished with my player movement and excited to move onto whats next

```
  if let location = touches.first?.location(in: self) {
    let horizontalAction = SKAction.move(to: location, duration: 1.0)
        horizontalAction.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.easeOut
      player?.run(horizontalAction)
```

Comment: You may want to go through this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/144-spritekit-animations-and-texture-atlases-in-swift .. at the end, the movement of the sprite changes each time the view is tapped.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for the link. I actually visited that page first to find out how to animate. I've done some modifications to his code to suite my purposes but it does the same thing. Now i'm trying to move it in a direction without stopping. As the camera is centered on the player sprite i want it to forever go to the direction of the mouse and not stop at the point first touched. Idk if that makes sense?

Comment: *"go to the direction of the mouse"* -- is this an iOS app or a MacOS (desktop) app?

Comment: @DonMag I apologize, I'm using the Xcode simulator so I was thinking mouse. An app, I meant touch.

Comment: I grabbed that AnimatedBear project... changed the size of the bear so it wasn't so big... implemented `touchesBegan()` and `touchesMoved()` with the same code as `touchesEnded()` and the bear follows my touch around.

Comment: @DonMag I apologize, I only looked at the picture of him clicking locations and the bear moving to those locations. I moved my code from touches began to touches moved, and now it follows the mouse when I hold it down / updates the location point. Thanks for the help, really appreciate you trying to help my dumb self out.